# How to create a generic interface of a method that returns a Type of a class that implements an interface?

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface

I'm looking for a way to define "MethodA" below, such that it returns a class definition (System.Type), of which an instance of said type implements "InterfaceB"

```
interface IMyInterface
{
  TType MethodA<TType, TInterface>() 
    : where TType : System.Type
    : where [instanceOf(TType)] : TInterface
}
```

*(Note: instanceOf is not real, of course...)*

I suspect it's not possible to get this kind of verification at compile time.  I'm hoping someone out there will prove me wrong.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

*EDIT: I've updated this in hopes of being more specific that what is returned is a System.Type, of which this later code can execute:*

```
var classType = myInterface.MethodA<(something, ISomeInterface)>();
ISomeInterface = new classType();  //--Assuming default constructor
```

*I haven't really focused on this part yet, just more curious about the theoretical construction of  my primary quesiton.*

Comment: Change the return type to `TInterface`

Comment: Are you using "Type" to mean `System.Type`, or to mean some type that you have defined?  In the former case, what you're trying to do is impossible for obvious reasons, and you should almost certainly not be deriving from `System.Type` anyway.

Comment: Yes, I mean System.Type.  I'm trying to see if I can get the class definition of something that implements the TInterface, of which I'll be 'newing' up later.  I'm trying to avoid having to new it up w/in this particular method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation:

```
// We have an interface...
interface InterfaceB {}

// And this class implements the interface.
class ImplementsB : InterfaceB {}

// But this class does not.
class DoesNotImplementB {}
```

You could define `MethodA` as:

```
static Type MethodA<TClass, TInterface>()
    where TClass : TInterface
{
    return typeof(TClass);
}
```

Then the following will work:

```
Type t = MethodA<ImplementsB, InterfaceB>();
```

But this gives a compile-time error:

```
Type t = MethodA<DoesNotImplementB, InterfaceB>();
```

> The type 'DoesNotImplementB' cannot be used as type parameter 'TClass' in the generic type or method 'MethodA<TClass,TInterface>()'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DoesNotImplementB' to 'InterfaceB'.

So, this way you are sure that the result of `MethodA` is a `Type` of a class that implements `TInterface`. Given that `Type` object, you can instantate it later like this:

```
public object Instantiate(Type type)
{
    // Call the default constructor.
    // You can change this to call any constructor you want.
    var constructor = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
    var instance = constructor.Invoke(new object[0]);
    return instance;
}
```

If you know that your `Type` is compatible with some interface `TInterface`, then you can avoid a cast with an additional method like this:

```
public TInterface Instantiate<TInterface>(Type type)
{
    return (TInterface)Instantiate(type);
}
```

However, if `type` is a `Type` that somehow does not implement `TInterface`, you'll get an `InvalidCastException` at run-time. There is no way to constrain `Type` to be a type that implements a particular interface at compile-time. However, at run-time you can check it to avoid the `InvalidCastException` exception:

```
public TInterface Instantiate<TInterface>(Type type)
{
    if (!typeof(TInterface).IsAssignableFrom(type))
        throw new Exception("Wrong type!");
    return (TInterface)Instantiate(type);
}
```

Note that `typeof(TType)` is an expression that results in a `Type` object, so everywhere you see `typeof()` you could replace it with any `Type` variable and vice versa.

Is this what you wanted to know?

Comment: Close, but I'm trying to avoid actually instantiating the object at this point.  I want to return the class definition itself, of which I can use to instantiate the object later.  My problem is I can't figure out a way to guarantee the (System.Type) returned, when instantiated, actually implements TInterface.  At least, not until I try to instantiate it and cast it to TInterface.  But that's a run-time solution, not a compile-time solution.

Comment: I updated my post. Is this closer to what you wanted to know?

Comment: I haven't forgotten about this, I just haven't had time to apply your ideas.  They sound good, maybe I'll get a chance to try them out this weekend, and update this comment block about it when I can.

Answer (score 3):

There are two interpretations of your question; one would be trivial, one impossible, so I'll go forward and cover both.

1. You want to return an instance of a type which implements both [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) and `TInterface`.

   This is trivial: Just use `where TType : Type` and `where TType : TInterface`.
2. You want to return an instance of [`System.Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) that represents a type which inherits from `TInterface`.

   This is impossible to specify in the .NET (and C#) type-system.

   The type system can only resolve information from the type hierarchy themselves, but not enforce "contracts" like restricted run-time property values.  There are a few hacks regarding default-constructors etc., but as far as I know not even testing for existing methods is possible (unlike C++ templates, for instance, not to speak of Qi et al.).

*Update*

Please check the comment from [Michael Graczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1301879/michael-graczyk).

Also: I just found out that there are code-contract checkers (static and run-time) for .NET: [Microsoft DevLabs Code-Contracts for .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx).  I have never used them, not even new about them, but that looks interesting!

However, even without looking, I'm quite sure that overload-resolution etc. will not be able to use such information.

Comment: 3. He is using the word "Type" for something other than `System.Type`.

Comment: You are so goddamn right about this.  Ouch.  For other readers: falls into class 2.) checking property-values won't work.

Comment: For #1, I'd simplify it as
    where TType : Type, TInterface